# Programmatically Creating Image Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, c#-4.0, dynamic

I want to create a Windows Toolbar (something like RocketDock) which dynamically creates buttons from serialized classes, but I can't figure out how to dynamically set the image.
As an aside, how should a image be serialized (i want to serialize the image with the storage class, instead of loading it from the original png file location each time)?

I found the following code to create a dependency property

```
public class ImageButton
{
    #region Image dependency property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty;

    public static ImageSource GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    static ImageButton()
    {
        var metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null);
        ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image",
                                                            typeof(ImageSource),
                                                            typeof(ImageButton), metadata);
    }
}
```

And i created a button style to inherit to set the image

```
        <Style x:Key="ImageButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=(Extender:ImageButton.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,0,0,0" Height="16" Width="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

but I can't figure out how to set the image from code after I create the button

```
var newButton = new Button();
var style = (Style)FindResource("ImageButton");
```

newButton.Image does not resolve.  Do I need to do something with style.Resources?

---

### **EDIT - response to Olli**

Thanks, but...  Using...

```
Link link = new Link(@"c:\temp\dev\ClearAllIcon.png");
    var newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Content = "bloberific";
    var style = (Style)FindResource("ImageButton");
    ImageButton.SetImage(newButton, link.IconSource);
    MainStack.Children.Add(newButton);
```

where link is defined as

```
public Link(string iconPath)
    {
        IconPath = iconPath;
        IconSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(iconPath));

    }
```

the image does not show, though the text does.  The button is normal looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not create a normal dependency property but an *attached* dependency property. Your newButton instance has no defined property "Image". Therfore you do not have the convenience CLR property getter/setter (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx#attached_properties_code) for details).

The code should look similar to this to set the image source value:

```
ImageButton.SetImage(newButton, imageSource);
```

Comment: See "EDIT - response to Olli"

Comment: I also had to change DataTemplate to ControlTemplate for it to use the image as the button, instead of putting the image on a normal button.

Answer (score 1):

```
Link link = new Link(@"c:\temp\dev\ClearAllIcon.png");
var newButton = new Button();
newButton.Content = "bloberific";
var style = (Style)FindResource("ImageButton");
ImageButton.SetImage(newButton, link.IconSource);
MainStack.Children.Add(newButton);
```

you do not use the style variable - is this the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me some time ago to create a little game.

```
var botao = sender as Button;
Image i = new Image();


i.Source= new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Resources/x.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
botao.Content = i;
```