# Adding an Image inside a Button programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, button, children

In WPF:

```
<Button Width="24" Height="24" >
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/res/x.png" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Button>
```

How can I mimic this in C#? I can't find any method in the `Button` class that adds children.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271277/programmatically-creating-image-button-in-wpf

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Button` is a `Content` control so you just have to use the `Buttons` `Content` property

Example:

```
Button myButton = new Button
{
    Width = 24,
    Height = 24,
    Content = new Image
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("image source")),
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
    }
};
```

Comment: What if I want to add image to the button with text content?